# ggplot2: add p-values to the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value

I got this plot

[image]

Using the code below

```
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

df <- diamonds %>%
  dplyr::filter(cut%in%c("Fair","Ideal")) %>%
  dplyr::filter(clarity%in%c("I1" ,  "SI2" , "SI1" , "VS2" , "VS1",  "VVS2")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(new_price = ifelse(cut == "Fair", 
                                   price* 0.5, 
                                   price * 1.1))

formula <- y ~ x    
ggplot(df, aes(x= new_price, y= carat, color = cut)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
  facet_wrap(~clarity, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = formula, se = F) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..rr.label..)), 
               label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.15,
               formula = formula, parse = TRUE, size = 3)
```

In addition to R2, I want to add p-values to the facets as well. I can do this manually through running the regression first then getting p-values and using `geom_text()` to add these p-values [similar to the answer of this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564434/automaticly-add-p-values-to-facet-plot)

Is there any faster or automated way to do that? e.g. similar to the way R2 values have been added.

**Update**

The p-value I'm talking about is the **slope p-value**. The trends are considered highly statistically significant when **p < 0.005**.

Comment: Isnt that a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564434/automaticly-add-p-values-to-facet-plot?lq=1). It basically tells you to use `summarize()`

Comment: Please, see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35140066/3817004) to [ggplot2: Adding Regression Line Equation and R2 on graph](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7549694/3817004) by the author of the `ggpmisc` package for more details or contact the author.

Comment: Did you take a look at `stat_fit_glance` ? source : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpmisc/vignettes/examples.html

Comment: p-value does not mean "the probability that each trend is significantly different from zero"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `stat_fit_glance` which is part of the `ggpmisc` package in R. This package is an extension of `ggplot2` so it works well with it.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= new_price, y= carat, color = cut)) +
       geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
       facet_wrap(~clarity, scales = "free_y") +
       geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = formula, se = F) +
       stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..rr.label..)), 
       label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.15,
       formula = formula, parse = TRUE, size = 3)+
       stat_fit_glance(method = 'lm',
                       method.args = list(formula = formula),
                       geom = 'text',
                       aes(label = paste("P-value = ", signif(..p.value.., digits = 4), sep = "")),
       label.x.npc = 'right', label.y.npc = 0.35, size = 3)
```

`stat_fit_glance` basically takes anything passed through `lm()` in R and allows it to processed and printed using `ggplot2`. The user-guide has the rundown of some of the functions like `stat_fit_glance`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpmisc/vignettes/user-guide.html. Also I believe this gives model p-value, not slope p-value (in general), which would be different for multiple linear regression. For simple linear regression they should be the same though.

Here is the plot:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your time and help. In my analysis, slope p-value is different from model p-value.

Comment: FYI there is a typo in your package name. It should be `ggpmisc`, not `ggmisc`. Cheers  :)

Comment: I get a `Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: label.x.npc, label.y.npc` and `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` if I copy and paste the data and formula from the question and the `ggplot` from the answer.

Comment: @CrunchyTopping `label.x.npc` and `label.y.npc` have both been deprecated. I suggest using `label.x` and `label.y`, also you may want to create a `my.formula <- y~x` and replace that with `formula = formula` into `formula = my.formula` and it should work.