# Add p-value and r on ggplot [Follow-up]

Tags: r, ggplot2

It is a follow-up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333151/add-p-value-and-r2-ggplot-follow-up). When I run the code given below, I get a plot with two R2 and p-value but p-value = 0. It is possibly due to very small p-value. I tried increasing no. of digits to 20 (here `signif(..p.value.., digits = 4)`) but it did not work. I would rather prefer to mention exact p-value or use stars e.g., `if (p<0.002) star='**' else if (p>=0.002&p<0.05) star='*' else star=''`. In addition, I would like to have r values listed in the plot. Have a look and please let me know which part needs to be amended.  Looking forward!

**UPDATE**

Answer codes by @eipi10 for adding p-value work, but still **seeking answers** on adding **correlation coefficient (r)** in the ggplots.

Code:

```
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

df <- diamonds %>%
  dplyr::filter(cut%in%c("Fair","Ideal")) %>%
  dplyr::filter(clarity%in%c("I1" ,  "SI2" , "SI1" , "VS2" , "VS1",  "VVS2")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(new_price = ifelse(cut == "Fair", 
                                   price* 0.5, 
                                   price * 1.1))

formula <- y ~ x - 1

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=factor(cut))) 
p <- p + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x-1, size = 1, level=0.95) 
p <- p + geom_point(alpha = 0.3) 
p <- p + stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..rr.label..)),
                      label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.15, formula = formula, 
                      parse = TRUE, size = 3) + 
          stat_fit_glance(method = 'lm', method.args = list(formula = formula),
                      geom = 'text', aes(label = paste("P-value = ", 
                      signif(..p.value.., digits = 4), sep = "")),label.x.npc = 'right',
                      label.y.npc = 0.35, size = 3)
print(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a large data set and you can see from the graph that the fit is almost perfect, which means the p-value for the regression is going to be miniscule. Below are regression models for each of the two levels of `cut`. To save space, only the key parts of the model summaries are shown:

```
lapply(unique(df$cut), function(g) {
  summary(lm(y ~ x - 1, df %>% filter(cut==g)))
})
```

> ```
> cut=="Ideal"
> ...
> Coefficients:
>   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> x 1.001715   0.000269    3724   <2e-16 ***
> ...
> Residual standard error: 0.2079 on 18291 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.9987,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9987 
> F-statistic: 1.387e+07 on 1 and 18291 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
>
> cut=="Fair"
> ...
> Coefficients:
>    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> x 0.9895032  0.0004096    2416   <2e-16 ***
> ...
> Residual standard error: 0.1033 on 1583 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.9997,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9997 
> F-statistic: 5.836e+06 on 1 and 1583 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
> ```

Note the enormous F statistics. The p-values for such large F statistics are essentially zero.

```
pf(5.836e06, 1, 1583, lower=FALSE)
```

> ```
> [1] 0
> ```

Any F statistic above about 2,400 (for the given degrees of freedom) will give a p-value below the smallest non-zero number that R can represent.

```
pf(2400, 1, 1583, lower=FALSE)
```

> ```
> [1] 1.716433e-319
> ```

By default, when R rounds a number, it doesn't return trailing zeros (try `round(1.340000, 5)` or `signif(1.340000,5)`). To get more zeros printed, you can, for example, use `sprintf` to format the output string. The code below formats the p-value in scientific notation. For decimal numbers replace `"%1.4e"` with `"%1.4f"`. See the help for more details on format strings:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=cut)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x-1, size = 1, level=0.95) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..rr.label..)),
               label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.15, formula = formula, 
               parse=TRUE, size = 3) + 
  stat_fit_glance(method = 'lm', method.args = list(formula = formula),
                  geom='text', aes(label=paste0("P-value = ", sprintf("%1.4e", ..p.value..))),
                  label.x.npc = 'right',
                  label.y.npc = 0.4, size = 3)
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** To add starred p-value ranges, one option is to use `ifelse` statements with p-value ranges as the conditions:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=cut)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x-1, size = 1, level=0.95) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..rr.label..)),
               label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.15, formula = formula, 
               parse=TRUE, size = 3) + 
  stat_fit_glance(method = 'lm', method.args = list(formula = formula),
                  geom='text', aes(label=ifelse(..p.value..< 0.001, "p<0.001**", 
                                                ifelse(..p.value..>=0.001 & ..p.value..<0.05, "p<0.05*", "p>0.05"))),
                  label.x.npc = 'right',
                  label.y.npc = 0.4, size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: You can get the p-value directly on the log(10) scale if you really need it: `pf(5.836e06, 1, 1583, lower=FALSE, log.p=TRUE)/log(10)` = -2824.782

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker. `if you really need it:`: You mean, in case I was worried about whether my p-value was really 1e-2800 instead of the stupendously greater 1e-315? Maybe this is a good time to link to [this article](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/signif4.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 & @BenBolker. I would prefer to use stars or mention exact p-value. e.g., `if (p<0.002) star='**' else if (p>=0.002&p<0.05) star='*' else star=''`. Any thoughts on adding correlation coefficient and stars? 

Ben, Where/how to incorporate your log(10) scale code in @eipi10 code?