# How do I indicate p-value and significance on a ggpredict graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble adding p-values and statistical significance indicators on on my `ggpredict` predicted probabilities graph. I have the following code:

```
library(ggeffects)
library(ggsignif)

set.seed(42)

# number of observations
n <- 20

# data frame
df <- data.frame(
  DV = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  IV = sample(0:2, n, replace = TRUE)
)


reg <- glm(DV ~ IV, data = df, family=binomial(probit))

graph <- ggpredict(reg, terms=c("IV")) %>% plot(ci = TRUE, colors = "bw", breaks=seq(0, 1, .25), limits=c(0, 1)) + labs(title = NULL, y="", x="") +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c(0, 1)), map_signif_level = TRUE)

graph
```

When I load the graph, I get the following error:

```
Error in `geom_signif()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
! Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a small update of your code. You could also have a look to these alternative answer

[ggplot2: add p-values to the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536950/ggplot2-add-p-values-to-the-plot)

[Add regression line equation and R^2 on graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/add-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph)

I have tested with two example, one in case you have no factor, and one if you have a factor variable (you will use ggsignif, only when you want to compare your different factor). Instead of using the direct plot function from ggpredict (2nd case with a factor variable) I have made a separate plot, where I kept outputs from ggpredict, and plot difference between factor (with ggsignif).

Update:
Note that the geom_signif is calculating its own p-value (based on wil-test), and does not reflect the p-value from your glm or other model when you compare factors together! In case, with geom_signif() you could write directly values (extract them from your model) and add them in the function `geom_signif()` with the  argument  `map_signif_level = FALSE, annotations = c('pval1', 'pval2','pval3')`

```
library(ggeffects)
library(ggsignif)
library(broom)

set.seed(42)

# number of observations
n <- 20

# data frame
df <- data.frame(
  DV = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  IV = sample(0:2, n, replace = TRUE)
)


formula = 'DV ~ IV'
model <- glm(formula, data = df, family=binomial(probit))
summary(model)

#create vector of your p val, need broom 
pval = round(tidy(model)$p.value[2],3)

#add geom text
graph <- ggpredict(reg, terms=c("IV")) %>% plot(ci = TRUE, colors = "bw", 
                                                breaks=seq(0, 1, .25), limits=c(0, 1)) + labs(title = NULL, y="", x="") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0.2, y = .9, label = paste0(" P = " , pval, sep = ""))) 

graph

#if factor.  

df$factor = as.factor(df$IV)
formulafactor = 'DV ~ factor'
model.factor <- glm(formulafactor, data = df, family=binomial(probit))

#alternativee model with a factor 
#we will make our own plot 
#pay attention to three different level of y_position (to avoid overlapping bracket)
ggpredict(model.factor, terms=c("factor")) %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = predicted))+
  geom_point(aes(group = 1))+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("0", "1"), 
                                 c('1', '2'), 
                                 c('2', '0')), map_signif_level = TRUE, tip_length = 0,
              y_position = c(.99, 1, 1.05))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), width = 0.02)+
  ylim(0,1.1) + 
  labs(title = NULL, y="", x="")+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I have an example where my coefficients for treatment 1 and treatment 2 are statistically significant from the control (when I do summary(model)), and on the graph they are showing up as NS.

Comment: Well, that's a good question, I am not expert with this package but it seems that the p-value printed here is coming from another test (wilcox.test), and would not reflect the output of your glm analysis. 
What you can do here is to add an extra argument in geom_signif(..., map_signif_level = FALSE, annotations = c('pval1', 'pval2','pval3')) where you change the different printed value on your plot. 

Alternatively, I am using another package, from here https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggpubr-how-to-add-p-values-generated-elsewhere-to-a-ggplot/ where I enter the p-value manually

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks!