# ggplot2 - One facceted plot does not show stat_compare_means Kruskal

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello when I try to plot this code :

```
ggplot(subset(tabcourt, !is.na(Score) & !is.na(`PSA level (ng/ml)`)))
+facet_wrap(.~Method,scales='free')
+aes(x =Score, y =`PSA level (ng/ml)`,color=Method)
+stat_compare_means(show.legend=FALSE,label.x.npc = 0.5,label.y.npc = 0.93,color="black",size=4)
+geom_boxplot()+theme_bw()
```

It doesn't show the Kruskal Wallis on the middle plot, I tried all I could but can't seem to have the solution, any ideas on how to fix this ?
[image: Plot description]

Edit : when putting free_y instead of free it fixes the bug but the x axis is bad (1 to 30 for each)

here's the head and the str of the data :
[image: Head description]
[image: Head description]

Comment: your bracketing is wierd, and `aes` usually gois inside a `geom` layer, not outside (I think). PLease include a sample of your data to make this reproducible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your error could come either how you wrapped your data into ggplot or from your data it self.

I don't have a sample of your data, so I used the sample database `Toothgrowth` and your code for `stat_compare_mean`, I get the display you are looking for.

Here is my code:

```r
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")

# Box plot faceted by "dose"
p <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "supp", y = "len",
               color = "supp", palette = "jco",
               add = "jitter",
               facet.by = "dose", short.panel.labs = FALSE)
# Adding stat_compare_means
p + stat_compare_means(show.legend=FALSE, label.x.npc = 0.5, 
                       label.y.npc = 0.93, color = "black", size = 4) + theme_bw()
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

If you use this instead, you have a better plotting:

```r
p + stat_compare_means() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

**UPDATE: TRICK TO GET THE FINAL PLOT DISPLAYED**

So, I tried to reproduce your data in order to reproduce the error of plotting you get and I succeed to plot the p values using a trick described in this post: [R: ggplot2 - Kruskal-Wallis test per facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536090/r-ggplot2-kruskal-wallis-test-per-facet)

Here is the code that I used to mimicks your data:

```r
set.seed(1)
# defining the sample dataset AJCC
PSA_levels <- rnorm(100,mean = 2, sd = 2)
AJCC_data <- data.frame(cbind(PSA_levels))
x <- NULL
for(i in 1:100) {x <- c(x,sample(1:4,1))}
AJCC_data$score <- x
AJCC_data$Method <- 'AJCC'

# defining the sample dataset Gleason
PSA_levels <- rnorm(100,mean = 2.5, sd = 1)
Gleason_data <- data.frame(cbind(PSA_levels))
x <- NULL
for(i in 1:100) {x <- c(x,sample(5:10,1))}
Gleason_data$score <- x
Gleason_data$Method <- 'Gleason'

# defining the sample dataset TNM
PSA_levels <- rnorm(100,mean = 2.5, sd = 1)
TNM_data <- data.frame(cbind(PSA_levels))
x <- NULL
for(i in 1:100) {x <- c(x,sample(1:30,1))}
TNM_data$score <- x
TNM_data$Method <- 'TNM'

df <- rbind(AJCC_data, Gleason_data, TNM_data)
df$score <- as.factor(df$score)
```

Here is the output of  df that looks similar to your data `tabcourt`

```r
> str(df)
'data.frame':   300 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ PSA_levels: num  0.747 2.367 0.329 5.191 2.659 ...
 $ score     : Factor w/ 30 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 3 3 ...
 $ Method    : chr  "AJCC" "AJCC" "AJCC" "AJCC" ...
```

Then, I tried to reproduce your boxplot faceted:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = score, y = PSA_levels, color = Method))
p <- g + facet_wrap(.~Method, scales = 'free_x')
p <- p + geom_boxplot()
p <- p + theme_bw()
```

When, I tried to add p values on the graph using the `stat_compare_means` function, I get same error of plotting as you. So, according to the post cited above, I used the package `dplyr` to generate the pvalue of the Kruskal Wallis test for each group.

```r
library(dplyr)
ptest <- df %>% group_by(Method) %>% summarize(p.value = kruskal.test(PSA_levels ~score)$p.value)
```

Here the output of ptest:

```r
> ptest
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Method  p.value
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 AJCC      0.575
2 Gleason   0.216
3 TNM       0.226
```

Now, I can add that the boxplot by doing:

```r
p + geom_text(data = ptest, aes(x =  c(2,3,10), y = c(6,6,6), label = paste0("Kruskal-Wallis\n p=",round(p.value,3))))
```

And here, what you get:
[image]

So, I think it is because `stat_compare_means` did not understand which group to compare and how to represent all statistical comparisons on the graph. Doing the test out of the `ggplot` and then adding as a `geom_text` argument solve the situation.

Hope it will works with your real data !

Comment: Hello, I tried yours and it worked but without a free_x, because when i added scale="free_x" then your code didn't work, so i tried on mine and when i remove the free scale it works.... but it's such a bad plot then... 

```compare_means(!is.na(`mtDNA copy number`) ~ !is.na(Score), data = tabcourt, group.by = "Method")``` strangely gives me ```Error: Strings must match column names. Unknown columns: !is.na(Score)```, I verified, Score is there
How can I give you my data ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake the correct code is `compare_means(!is.na("mtDNA copy number") ~ !is.na("Score"), data = tabcourt, group.by = "Method")`. (I forget brackets on Score). Try that, it should work. By the way, there is no `free-x` on my code, where did you see that ?

Comment: I tried it because there is one on mine, without that I have 1 to 30 for x on each axis,  [https://i.ibb.co/frX7Tm8/Capture.png](https://i.ibb.co/frX7Tm8/Capture.png) here's the head !
Same error tho :
```> compare_means(!is.na("mtDNA copy number") ~ !is.na("Score"), data = tabcourt, group.by = "Method")
Error: Strings must match column names. Unknown columns: !is.na("Score")
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace```

Comment: Sorry forgot ```str(tabcourt)``` here it is :
[https://i.ibb.co/Wp5fxrW/Capture2.png](https://i.ibb.co/Wp5fxrW/Capture2.png)
Thank you for your kind help !

Comment: Just a quick comment, in your code, you have `aes(x =Score, y =`PSA level(ng/ml)`, color = Method)`, is it not supposed to be `mtDNA copy number` ?

Comment: Oopsie, it's supposed to be PSA, ```ggplot(subset(tabcourt, !is.na(Score) & !is.na(`PSA level (ng/ml)`)))+facet_wrap(.~Method,scales='free')+aes(x =Score, y =`PSA level (ng/ml)`,color=Method)+stat_compare_means(show.legend=FALSE,label.x.npc = 0.5,label.y.npc = 0.93,color="black",size=4)+geom_boxplot()+theme_bw()``` thank you

Comment: @MrIce, I edited my answer to provide you a way to get the plot you are looking for. Hope it will works for you. Keep me update

Answer (score 0):

thank you for this workaround !!! It did work, but I had to add : `+scale_x_discrete()` otherwise I'd get `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

Here's the code I used if this happens to others :

```r
ptest = tabcourt %>% group_by(Method) %>%summarize(p.value=kruskal.test("mtDNA copy number"~Score)$p.value)
p2 = ggplotly(ggplot(subset(tabcourt, !is.na(Score) & !is.na("mtDNA copy number")),aes(x =Score, y ="mtDNA copy number",color=Method)) 
+ scale_x_discrete()
+ geom_text(data = ptest, aes(x =c(2,3,10), y= c(1.5,1.5,1.5), label = paste0("Kruskal-Wallis\n p=",round(p.value,3))))
+ facet_grid(.~Method,scales='free')
+ geom_boxplot()
+ theme_bw())
```

Weird tho that stat_compare_means have an hard time doing it's job !

Comment: Great that it is working for you !  Apparently, `stat_compare_means` is more limited that `compare_means` and for example can take the output of `compare_means` as an argument. Maybe in a near future, new versions of this function will solve this issue.