# Error adding the Kruskal Wallis pvalue into boxplots with facet_grid in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, facet-grid, kruskal-wallis

I am trying to add the Kruskal Wallis pvalue to my boxplots and although I have seen a lot of posts with the solution, I cannot make it work.

This is my data and the code to run the boxplots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1234)
Gene <- floor(runif(25, min=0, max=101))
Age <- floor(runif(25, min=18, max=75))
Group <- c("Group1", "Group1", "Group3", "Group2", "Group1", "Group3", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group1", "Group1", "Group3", "Group1", "Group2", "Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group1", "Group3", "Group3", "Group2", "Group1", "Group3", "Group3","Group2")


df <- data.frame(Gene, Age, Group)

mybreaks <- seq(min(df$Age)-1, to=max(df$Age)+10, by=10)
df$groups_age <- cut(df$Age, breaks = mybreaks, by=10)

bp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=groups_age, y=Gene, group=groups_age)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=groups_age)) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ Group)

bp
```

[image: image 1]

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536090/r-ggplot2-kruskal-wallis-test-per-facet), I see one way to do it, but when I try to do the same, I get this error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'groups_age' not found` and the plot is not shown.

The code:

```
pv <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(Kruskal_pvalue = kruskal.test(Gene ~ groups_age)$p.value)

bp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=groups_age, y=Gene, group=groups_age)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=groups_age)) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ Group) +
  geom_text(data=pv, aes(x=2, y=75, label=paste0("Kruskal-Wallis\n p=",Kruskal_pvalue)))
bp
```

Note that I put x and y manually, just to place the value. However, I would like to do it more automatically, depending on the value of the gene if it changes.

Does anyone know why I am getting that error and why it is not working?

Thanks very much in advance

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you made `group=groups_age` a global aesthetic. All layers will inherit the global aes and hence all layers will look for a column called `groups_age` in the data provided to the layer. As the data `pv` used in `geom_text` does not contain a column of this name you get an error.

To solve your issue you could drop `group=groups_age` as it is not needed in your case. For more general cases you have to be more specific what you make a `local` or `global` aes. Additionally each geom has an `inherits.aes` argument (which by default is `TRUE`) to prevent that global aes are inherited:

```r
library(ggplot2)

bp <- ggplot(df, aes(x = groups_age, y = Gene)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = groups_age)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Group) +
  geom_text(data = pv, aes(x = 2, y = 75, label = paste0("Kruskal-Wallis\n p=", Kruskal_pvalue)))
bp
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>